# delegate keyword vs. lambda notation

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda, anonymous-methods

Once it is compiled, is there a difference between:

```
delegate { x = 0; }
```

and

```
() => { x = 0 }
```

?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Short answer : no.

Longer answer that may not be relevant:

- If you assign the lambda to a delegate type (such as `Func` or `Action`) you'll get an anonymous delegate.
- If you assign the lambda to an Expression type, you'll get an expression tree instead of a anonymous delegate.  The expression tree can then be compiled to an anonymous delegate.

Edit:
Here's some links for Expressions.

- [System.Linq.Expression.Expression(TDelegate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) (start here).
- Linq in-memory with delegates (such as System.Func) uses [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx).  Linq to SQL (and anything else) with expressions uses [System.Linq.Queryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable_members.aspx).  Check out the parameters on those methods.
- An [Explanation from ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/08/new-orcas-language-feature-lambda-expressions.aspx).  In a nutshell, Linq in-memory will produce some anonymous methods to resolve your query.  Linq to SQL will produce an expression tree that represents the query and then translate that tree into T-SQL.  Linq to Entities will produce an expression tree that represents the query and then translate that tree into platform appropriate SQL.

Comment: An Expression type?  This sounds like new territory to me.  Where can I find out more about Expression types and using expression trees in C#?

Comment: Even longer answer - there are fiddly reasons why they're convertible to different delegate types, too :)

Comment: Note that the lambda can only be assigned to an Expression type, if it is an expression lambda.

Answer (score 130):

I like Amy's answer, but I thought I'd be pedantic. The question says, "Once it is compiled" - which suggests that both expressions *have* been compiled. How could they both compile, but with one being converted to a delegate and one to an expression tree? It's a tricky one - you have to use another feature of anonymous methods; the only one which isn't shared by lambda expressions. If you specify an anonymous method without specifying a parameter list *at all* it is compatible with any delegate type returning void and without any `out` parameters. Armed with this knowledge, we should be able to construct two overloads to make the expressions completely unambiguous but very different.

But disaster strikes! At least with C# 3.0, you can't convert a lambda expression with a block body into an expression - nor can you convert a lambda expression with an assignment in the body (even if it is used as the return value). This may change with C# 4.0 and .NET 4.0, which allow more to be expressed in an expression tree. So in other words, with the examples MojoFilter happened to give, the two will *almost* always be converted to the same thing. (More details in a minute.)

We can use the delegate parameters trick if we change the bodies a little bit though:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int x = 0;
        Foo( () => x );
        Foo( delegate { return x; } );
    }

    static void Foo(Func<int, int> action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I suspect the anonymous method...");
    }

    static void Foo(Expression<Func<int>> func)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I suspect the lambda expression...");
    }
}
```

But wait! We can differentiate between the two even without using expression trees, if we're cunning enough. The example below uses the overload resolution rules (and the anonymous delegate matching trick)...

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Base
{
    public void Foo(Action action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I suspect the lambda expression...");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public void Foo(Action<int> action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I suspect the anonymous method...");
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        int x = 0;
        d.Foo( () => { x = 0; } );
        d.Foo( delegate { x = 0; } );
    }
}
```

Ouch. Remember kids, every time you overload a method inherited from a base class, a little kitten starts crying.

Comment: I got out my popcorn and read the whole thing.  That's some distinction that I would probably never think about even if I was staring it right in the face.

Comment: Okay, removing the whiny bit at the end as clearly some people *have* read it :)

Comment: I knew some of this, but I must congratulate you on your ability to communicate it to humans.

Comment: For anybody interested in the changes in .NET 4.0 (based on the CTP) - see http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/future-expressions.html . Note that C# 4.0 doesn't do anything new yet as far as I can tell.

Comment: Jon, you rock.

Erik, to be a true Skeet fanboi, you should be subscribed to his stack overflow rss like I am. Just stick http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656 into your feed reader.

Comment: You: _If you specify an anonymous method without specifying a parameter list_ at all _it is compatible with any delegate type returning void and without any ref/out parameters._ Actually `ref` parameters are OK (the anonymous method without parameter list is still compatible). But with an `out` parameter it can't work, since the body of the method must necessarily use all `out` parameters.

Comment: Actually I can write a usual (named) method which doesn't use its `out` parameters by ensuring that the method never returns. I can do this with an infinite loop, or do it by having all execution paths throw an exception. But with the anonymous method, the compiler requires me to specify the parameters if some of them are `out`, even if I don't use them (because my anonymous method can't `return`). So your answer is correct now.

Comment: @jon I don't understand  - how can `delegate { return x; }` go to `Func<int,int > action`  - the signature is not the same - the latter has _extra_ `int` param type. can you please shed light ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you use an anonymous method without a parameter list, that's compatible with *any* delegate type with non-ref/out parameters, so long as the return type is compatible. Basically you're saying "I don't care about the parameters". Note that `delegate { ... }` is *not* the same as `delegate() { ... }` - the latter is only compatible with a parameterless delegate type.

Comment: "Ouch. Remember kids, every time you overload a method inherited from a base class, a little kitten starts crying."
I need this on a t-shirt.

Answer (score 4):

In the two examples above there's no difference, zero.

The expression:

```
() => { x = 0 }
```

is a Lambda expression with statement body, so it can't be compiled as an expression tree. In fact it doesn't even compile because it needs a semicolon after 0:

```
() => { x = 0; } // Lambda statement body
() => x = 0      // Lambda expression body, could be an expression tree.
```

Comment: Surely that means there's a difference of "one will compile, the other won't" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Amy B is correct.  Note that there can be advantages to using expression trees.  LINQ to SQL will examine the expression tree and convert it to SQL.

You can also play tricks with lamdas and expression trees to effectively pass the names of class members to a framework in a refactoring-safe way.  [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) is an example of this.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference

Example:

```
var mytask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return 2712;
});
mytask.ContinueWith(delegate
{
    _backgroundTask.ContinueTask(() =>lblPercent.Content = mytask.Result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
});
```

And I replace with lambda:(error)

```
var mytask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return 2712;
});
mytask.ContinueWith(()=>
{
    _backgroundTask.ContinueTask(() =>lblPercent.Content = mytask.Result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
});
```

Comment: Wrong~lambda failed just because method parameter signature doesn't match.

Answer (score -2):

Some basics here.

This is a anonymous method

```
(string testString) => { Console.WriteLine(testString); };
```

As anonymous methods do not have names we need a delegate in which we can assign both of these methods or expressions. e.g.

```
delegate void PrintTestString(string testString); // declare a delegate

PrintTestString print = (string testString) => { Console.WriteLine(testString); }; 
print();
```

---

Same with the lambda expression. Usually we need a delegate to use them

```
s => s.Age > someValue && s.Age < someValue    // will return true/false
```

We can use a func delegate to use this expression.

```
Func< Student,bool> checkStudentAge = s => s.Age > someValue && s.Age < someValue ;

bool result = checkStudentAge ( Student Object);
```