# What does $_ mean in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've seen the following a lot in PowerShell, but what does it do exactly?

```
$_
```

Comment: The question has, of course, been answered for the single special token given, but for a wallchart illustrating _all_ of PowerShell's special tokens, take a look at [The Complete Guide to PowerShell Punctuation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/the-complete-guide-to-powershell-punctuation/)

Comment: As of this writing, the official description of the [automatic $_ variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) (whose alias is `$PSItem`) is unfortunately terse. See also the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55667981/45375), which tries to provide a systematic overview of all contexts in which `$_` / `$PSItem` is meaningfully defined.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

This is the variable for the current value in the pipe line, which is called `$PSItem` in Powershell 3 and newer.

```
1,2,3 | %{ write-host $_ }
```

or

```
1,2,3 | %{ write-host $PSItem }
```

For example in the above code the `%{}` block is called for every value in the array.  The `$_` or `$PSItem` variable will contain the current value.

Comment: It's not necessarily related to the pipeline. It's more a "current argument to the currently executing script block". For example while you can use it just fine in `ForEach-Object` or `Where-Object` you can't use it in something like `Get-Foo|Add-Member NoteProperty Bar ($_.SomeProperty)` – there's a pipeline involved, but no script block and therefore no `$_`. (That being said, the PowerShell help also refers to the pipeline for `$_`. Confusing.)

Comment: @Joey you can absolutely use $_ in your example. `Get-Foo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Bar -Value $_.SomeProperty `

Comment: @Xalorous: Just because it doesn't produce an error doesn't mean it works: `Get-ChildItem | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Bar -Value $_.Name -PassThru | Select Bar` ... Well, it *can* work if you have a `$_` in the scope where you're executing that pipeline. But that's very different from what you usually mean when trying to write something like that.

Comment: @Joey `$_` in what you wrote is, for some reason, not looping through all the objects.  Try this instead.  `gci | % { $_ | add-member -Type NoteProperty -Name Bar -Value $_.name -PassThru } | Select Bar`.  I suspect that having `gci | cmdlet` without the explicit foreach is gathering up gci results and passing an array to the cmdlet.  However, the array is an object, so it's adding a property to the array object.  The array does not have a 'name' property, so the value assigned to $_.Bar is $null. Bottom line is that $_ is used extensively w/ pipelining. Not needing %{} to loop through is new.

Comment: Working version with extra pipeline removed.  `gci | % { add-member -InputObject $_ -Type NoteProperty -Name Bar -Value $_.name -PassThru } | Select Bar`

Comment: Within a PS script $_ also refers to the current directory of the execuring shell if used in the context of a path argument, for example: `Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -File`

Answer (score 49):

I think the easiest way to think about this variable like input parameter in lambda expression in C#. I.e. `$_` is similar to `x` in `x => Console.WriteLine(x)` anonymous function in C#. Consider following examples:

PowerShell:

```
1,2,3 | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_}
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
```

or

```
1,2,3 | Where-Object {$_ -gt 1}
```

Prints:

```
2
3
```

And compare this with C# syntax using LINQ:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
list.ForEach( _ => Console.WriteLine( _ ));
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
```

or

```
list.Where( _ => _ > 1)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Prints:

```
2
3
```

Comment: In C# don't use `_` as input parameter in lambda. `_` is sometimes used when the parameters is ignored, use x instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424775/is-there-a-better-way-to-express-a-parameterless-lambda-than

Comment: I don't think Sergey meant for the reader to use that exact syntax, it was simply a demonstration of how it worked.

Answer (score 35):

According to [this](http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens) website, it's a reference to `this`, mostly in loops.

> $_ (dollar underscore)
>   'THIS' token. Typically refers to the
>   item inside a foreach loop. 
>   Task:
>   Print all items in a collection.
>   Solution. ... | foreach { Write-Host
>   $_ }

Comment: `this` is a rather confusing term for the `$_` variable. In OOP it usually refers to the class, not a variable.

Comment: @remco especially when PS v5 adds a $this variable for use in classes.

Answer (score 14):

[$_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#_) is an alias for automatic variable $PSItem (introduced in PowerShell V3.0; [Usage information found here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/04/15/working-with-the-new-psitem-automatic-variable-in-windows-powershell-3-0/)) which represents the current item from the pipe.

PowerShell (v6.0) online documentation for automatic variables is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 4):

`$_` is a variable created by the system usually inside block expressions that are referenced by cmdlets that are used with pipe such as `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object`.

But it can be used also in other types of expressions, for example with `Select-Object` combined with expression properties. `Get-ChildItem | Select-Object @{Name="Name";Expression={$_.Name}}`. In this case the `$_` represents the item being piped but multiple expressions can exist.

It can also be referenced by custom parameter validation, where a script block is used to validate a value. In this case the `$_` represents the parameter value as received from the invocation.

The closest analogy to c# and java is the lamda expression. If you break down powershell to basics then everything is a script block including a script file a, functions and cmdlets. You can define your own parameters but in some occasions one is created by the system for you that represents *the input item to process/evaluate*. In those situations the automatic variable is `$_`.

Answer (score 1):

$_ is an variable which iterates over each object/element passed from the previous | (pipe).

Answer (score 0):

The $_ is a $PSItem, which is essentially an object piped from another command.
For example, running Get-Volume on my workstations returns Rows of PSItems, or objects

```
get-volume | select driveLetter,DriveType   

driveLetter DriveType
----------- ---------
      D      Fixed
             Fixed
      C      Fixed
      A      Removable
```

Driveletter and DriveType are properties
Now, you can use these item properties when piping the output with $_.(propertyName). (Also remember % is alias for Foreach-Object) For example

```
$vol = get-volume | select driveLetter,DriveType

$vol | Foreach-Object {
    if($_.DriveType -eq "Fixed") {
        "$($_.driveLetter) is $($_.driveType)"}
     else{
        "$($_.driveLetter) is $($_.driveType)"
     }
 }
```

Using Terinary in Powershell 7, I am able to shorten the logic while using properties from the Piped PSItem