# Running a function error

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am getting the following error when I run the function below:

> Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'.
>   The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or
>   empty and then try the command again. At
>   C:\Users\usernameone\Desktop\script.ps1:16 char:29
>   + Invoke-Command -ComputerName <<<<  $_ -ScriptBlock $s -Credential $cred
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,    $secstr
$_="192.168.10.4"

function test{
    $s = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("mkdir C:\'Documents and    Settings'\username\Desktop\Testfolder")
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock $s -Credential $cred 
}
```

Do you have any ideas as to what I've done wrong?

Comment: Syntax is `function test() { ... }`

Comment: `$_` is not defined in your function. Use a function  parameter.

Comment: How do i use a function parameter?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell

Comment: I just want to run the function without entering parameters.. So i just want to type the function name test! and would like to execute the command and make a new directory on the remote computer.

Comment: Yeah but why is your variable called `$_`. It's reserved for the current value in an iteration e.g. `foreach`. And I cannot see your function call. Is there some more code? If you call your function as @x0n said, that it could make sense. If you want your function to create a folder everytime on the same machine, then don't use a variable. But if you want your function to create the folder on different machines your function should know on which computer you want the folder. That is normally done with a function parameter.

Comment: Oh man i didn't realise that $_ was reserved i just renamed it and it worked! Thanks man..I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I posted it as my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your variable `$_` and it will work...

**Explanation:**

`$_` is "reserved" for the current value in an iteration e.g. `foreach` or a pipeline. See here: [What does $_ mean in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494115/what-does-mean-in-powershell)

If you call your function as @x0n said, then it could make sense. If you want your function to create a folder everytime on the same machine, then don't use a variable. But if you want your function to create the folder on different machines your function should know on which computer you want the folder. That is normally done with a function parameter.

```
[...]
$ipaddress = "192.168.10.4";

function test([string]$ip, [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$credentials) {
    $s = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("mkdir C:\'Documents and    Settings'\username\Desktop\Testfolder");
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ip -ScriptBlock $s -Credential $credentials;
}

// then call it like this
test $ipaddress $cred;
```

Here is a list of all those reserved things: http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens

Answer (score 1):

The special variable `$_` is only populated when the function or scriptblock containing it is involved in an active pipeline. It should work if you invoke `test` like this:

```
PS> "computername" | test
```

Follow?

As an aside, why are you creating a scriptblock in that awkward fashion? Use literal syntax:

```
$s = { mkdir 'c:\...\blah' }
```

If you want to create scriptblocks programmatically from text, there's an easier way:

```
$s = [scriptblock]::create('...')
```

Don't forget to use single quotes if you **don't want** references to variables to be resolved **before** the scriptblock is parsed.

Comment: it does not work! I am still getting the same error :S..I just typed "computername" | test within the console in powershell ISE and i received the same error.. Sorry i am new to powershell

Comment: thats because your function does not use pipeline input, you should eiter work with parameters, hardcode your values or read up on the basics first