# powershell v2 - rename a file whose name matches a string containing a wildcard

Tags: powershell-2.0, wildcard, rename

I'm trying to create a script to rename a file that matches a given filename, with a wildcard character. e.g.

I have a folder containing the following files:

- 201412180900_filename_123.log
- 201412181000_filename_123.log
- 201412181100_filename_456.log
- filename_789.log

I want to scan through this folder, and append the current time to the start of any file starting with the word 'filename'

I have the following so far:

```
$d = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMddHHmm" 
$dir = "C:\test"
$file = "filename*.log"

get-childitem -Path "$dir" | where-object { $_.Name -like "$file" } | rename-item -path $_ -newname $d."_".$_.name
```

but it doesn't work. 
As I see it the individual sections 'should' work from my reading of the documentation, but clearly something is wrong. If someone can point it out it would be appreciated.

---

We're getting closer. It would appear that `-path` in the `rename-item` section needs to be `$dir$_` as `$_` (seemingly) only contains the filename. (The get-help example suggests it needs to be the full path and filename)

If I take out the rename-item section and replace it with `%{write-host $d"_"$_}` it gives the correct new filename

However, simply placing this into `rename-item` section still doesn't update the filename.

```
rename-item -path $dir$_ -newname $d"_"$_
```

---

SUCCESS

the correct syntax appears to be:

```
get-childitem -Path "$dir" | where-object { $_.Name -like "$file" } | %{rename-item -path $dir$_ -newname $d"_"$_}
```

The missing element was the `%{ ... }` surrounding the `rename-item` section which enabled me to reference `$_`

Comment: What *is* happening when you run it, if I might ask?

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't useful in attempting to help you. Describe what happens and what you expected to happen.

Comment: sorry, I should have been clearer, Basically when I run it nothing happens. No error message. But the filename doesn't change. What I was expecting to happen was either get an error message, or the filename should change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$d = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMddHHmm" 
$dir = "C:\test"
$file = "filename*.log"

get-childitem -Path $dir | where-object { $_.Name -like $file } | %{ rename-item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "$d`_$($_.name)" }
```

This should work, assuming that the errors were relating to "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path'", and the NewName string.

Issues included:

- Not being able to reference $_ when not in a foreach style block ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494115/what-does-mean-in-powershell))
- The Concatenation issue [raised by @alroc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27565856/1112679)

You could, instead of passing the pipeline object to a `Foreach-Object`, pass directly to the `Rename-Item` - but I'm unsure quite how to reference the name of the object for the `-NewName` parameter.

Comment: Could also use `GCI -Path $dir -Filter $file` instead of the Where-Object, but I suspect that's PoSHv3+.

Comment: cheers for a good point about the $_ in a foreach loop, but still no joy

Comment: cheers, your examples got me there in the end, with the `%{...}` in order to use `$_` outside a `foreach` loop

Comment: Just as a quick comment: `%{ <#content#> }` is an alias for `ForEach-Object -Process { <#content#> }`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall `.` being a string concatenation operator in PowerShell (I may be wrong). Try this:

```
rename-item -path $_ -newname "$d_$($_.name)"
```

Or this

```
rename-item -path $_ -newname ($d + "_" + $_.name)
```

Or even this

```
rename-item -path $_ -newname ({0}_{1} -f $d,$_.name)
```

See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15113413/1324345)

Comment: From a little experimentation a moment ago, `"$d_$($_.name)"` attempts to get `$d_ + $($_.name)`. I attempted to solve this by adding "` " - would be curious about a better method, though. You are right about `.`.

Comment: cheers, I tried the + and that didn't work, but it didn't 'look' right without some kind of concatenation operator. And I thought I had read about using . to join strings (apparently I hadn't). Unfortunately none of the options above worked. The first two did nothing (didn't update the filename), and the last one gave various 'unexpected token' errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it without using foreach or %, but a script block instead:

```
get-childitem -Path "$dir" -filter $file | rename-item -newname { $d + "_" + $_.name }
```

See the examples in the doc for rename-item:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item  There's a -replace operator too, but it can't use wildcards?  Oh, you don't need wildcards:

```
get-childitem -Path "$dir" -filter $file | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace 'filename',($d + '_filename') }
```