# Update Field in CSV with PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0, export-to-csv

I have a large data set in a CSV file of which I'm attemting to update the records without success.

Here is what I have:

```bsh
$MailData = Import-Csv $MailDB -Delimiter '|'

$update = $MailData | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.subject -like 'GGN*') {
    $_.status = 1
    $_.status_modified = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss')
  }
}

$update | Export-Csv $MailDB -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

I've also tried the `-Append` switch and tried to do it with `Set-Content`. In all cases the content of `$MailData` is changed, but when I re-import the CSV file the data is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output the records at the end of the `ForEach-Object` loop, otherwise the result wouldn't have any data and you'd effectively truncate your file.

```bsh
(Import-Csv $MailDB -Delimiter '|') | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.subject -like 'GGN*') {
        $_.status = 1
        $_.status_modified = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss')
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv $MailDB -Delimiter '|' -NoType
```

Comment: I've been away from PowerShell for roughly four years.  I completely forgot what the $_ was for.  $_ is an alias for automatic variable $PSItem.  You an find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494115/what-does-mean-in-powershell