# Export data based on foreach login [Powershell]

Tags: powershell, foreach, import-csv, export-csv

I have simple csv file with column 'logins'

```
logins
john
mark
maria
...
```

Have powershell script to check their last logontime:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName)
{
    $time = 0
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName | Get-ADObject -Properties lastLogon
    if($user.LastLogon -gt $time)
    {
        $time = $user.LastLogon
    }
    $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
    Write-Host $username $dt }

import-csv -Encoding UTF8 -path C:\scripts\loginy.csv | foreach {
    Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName  $_.logins
}
```

This works fine with output

```
john 2018-05-10 14:11:28
mark 2018-11-29 14:26:58
maria 2018-11-02 11:14:17
...
```

When I try to export results it to csv file by code

```
$users = import-csv -Encoding UTF8 -path C:\scripts\loginy.csv
$results = @()
foreach ($_.logins in $users) {
    $results += Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName  $_.logins
}
$results | Export-CSV C:\scripts\Eksporty\logowania.csv -Append -encoding "utf8"
```

getting error

```
At C:\scripts\OstatnieLogowanie.ps1:19 char:12
+ foreach ($_.logins in $users) {
    +            ~
    Missing 'in' after variable in foreach loop.
    At C:\scripts\OstatnieLogowanie.ps1:19 char:29
    + foreach ($_.logins in $users)

}
```

I can't get it work over 2 hours :/

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I've confused LastLogon and LastLogonTimestamp.  LastLogonDate is based on LastLogonTimestamp.  The differences between these properties are explained [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx) and [here](http://directoryadmin.blogspot.com/2018/07/lastlogon-vs-lastlogontimestamp-vs.html).  I will come back and update my answer.

---

You're using `Write-Host` to output data:

```
Write-Host $username $dt
```

This won't work.  `Write-Host` means "write to the console screen, not to standard output." That will work just fine if you're trying to display data, but calling `$x = Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName  $login` will print the results to the console screen and nothing would be assigned to the `$x` variable.  For example:

```
PS C:\> $x = Write-Host 0
0
PS C:\> $x
PS C:\>
```

See how Write-Host still wrote to the console and `$x` doesn't have a value?

Your function should look something like `$username, $dt` or `Write-Output $username, $dt` or `return $username, $dt`.

Although that's still not really going to work like you want.  I would probably use a custom object (see `Get-Help about_Object_Creation -ShowWindow`) like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
function Get-ADUserLastLogon([string]$userName) {
    $user = Get-ADUser $userName -Properties LastLogonDate 
    [PSCustomObject]@{'Logins' = $username; 'LastLogonDate' = $user.LastLogonDate}
}

$users = import-csv -Encoding UTF8 -path C:\scripts\loginy.csv
$results = foreach ($user in $users) {
    Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName  $user.logins
}
$results | Export-CSV C:\scripts\Eksporty\logowania.csv -Append -encoding "utf8"
```

Frankly, however, if I were doing what you're trying to do here, my actual code would look like this:

```
Import-Csv -Encoding -Path C:\scripts\loginy.csv |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty logins |
    Get-ADUser -Properties LastLogonDate |
    Select-Object @{n = 'Logins'; e = {$_.SamAccountName}}, LastLogonDate |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\scripts\Eksporty\logowania.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

`Select-Object -ExpandProperty logins` will pass just the bare value of the logins column. Get-ADUser accepts identities from the pipeline, and it fetches the LastLogonDate for each user, as long as the SamAccountName (a default property) which is the logon name.

The next line, `Select-Object @{n = 'Logins'; e = {$_.SamAccountName}}, LastLogonDate` uses a calculated property (See the examples in `Get-Help Select-Object -ShowWindow`) to rename the SamAccountName property in a column named Logins.  You could use `Select-Object SamAccountName, LastLogonDate` if you don't care about the column name.  And the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter on `Export-Csv` just keeps it from adding that annoying "#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" nonsense on the first line.

Comment: Thanks for detailed information. Your codes works but logon date is different that from my function. I've checked which date is proper with cmd: net user %login% /domain  and your script has wrong date....

Comment: @CurlUser Ah, you're right.  I'm confusing LastLogon and LastLogonTimestamp.  LastLogonDate is based on LastLogonTImestamp.  Differences are explained [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx).  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[$_ is the variable for the current value in pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494115/what-does-mean-in-powershell). In your second part of code, since you don't have a pipeline, hence `$_` is empty and doesn't have any property/method associated with it.

What you can do is -

```
$users = import-csv -Encoding UTF8 -path C:\scripts\loginy.csv
foreach ($user in $users) {
Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName  $user.logins | Export-CSV C:\scripts\Eksporty\logowania.csv -Append -encoding "utf8"
}
```

**OR**

```
$users = import-csv -Encoding UTF8 -path C:\scripts\loginy.csv
foreach ($_ in $users) {
Get-ADUserLastLogon -UserName  $_.logins | Export-CSV C:\scripts\Eksporty\logowania.csv -Append -encoding "utf8"
}
```

Although I would recommend not using the latter since `$_` is an automatic variable `$PSItem` and beside you can have plenty other names for a variable which are not keywords, functions etc.

The use of `+=` to extend an array requires creating a new instance behind the scenes in every iteration.

Comment: Rebuilding the array with += on every iteration is inefficient, better assign the output of the foreach directly to the variable `$results = foreach (`

Comment: Not exactly, when exporting directly, you don't need the `$results` variable at all.

Comment: doesn work...At C:\scripts\OstatnieLogowanie.ps1:19 char:3
+ } | Export-CSV C:\scripts\Eksporty\logowania.csv -Append -encoding "u ...
+   ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: @CurlUser - Try it now.