# Why can't I use $_ in write-host?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, automatic-variable

I am trying to pipe an array of strings to write-host and explicitly use `$_` to write those strings:

```
'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | write-host $_
```

However, it fails with:

> *The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.*

This error message makes no sense to me because I am perfectly able to write

```
'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | write-host
```

I would have expected both pipelines to be equivalent. Apparently, they're not. So, what's the difference?

Comment: $_ is the current object for cmdlet's like `ForEach-Object`, like: `'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | ForEach-Object {write-host $_}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- The **[automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) and its *alias*, `$PSItem`, only ever have meaningful values *inside script blocks* (`{ ... }`)**, in **specific contexts**.
- The bottom section lists all relevant contexts.

  - *Update*: A new conceptual help topic, [about_PSItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSItem), is now available, which covers most of what is in the bottom section.

---

> I would have expected both pipelines to be equivalent.

They're not:

> `'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | write-host`

It is the pipeline-based equivalent of the following (equivalent in ultimate effect, not technically):

```bash
foreach ($str in 'foo', 'bar', 'baz') { Write-Host -Object $str }
```

That is, in your command `Write-Host` receives input from the pipeline that *implicitly* binds to its `-Object` parameter *for each input object*, by virtue of parameter `-Object` being declared as accepting pipeline input via attribute `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]`

---

> `'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | write-host $_`

*Before* pipeline processing begins, *arguments* - `$_` in your case - are bound to parameters *first*:

Since `$_` isn't preceded by a parameter name, it binds *positionally* to the - implied - `-Object` parameter.

Then, when pipeline processing begins, *pipeline* parameter binding finds no pipeline-binding `Write-Host` parameter to bind to anymore, given that the only such parameter, `-Object` *has already been bound*, namely by an *argument* `$_`.

In other words: **your command mistakenly tries to bind the `-Object` parameter *twice*;** unfortunately, the error message doesn't exactly make that clear.

The larger point is that **using `$_` only ever makes sense *inside a script block* (`{ ... }`)** that is evaluated *for each input object*.
Outside that context, `$_` (or its alias, `$PSItem`) typically has no value and shouldn't be used - **see the bottom section for an overview of all contexts** in which `$_` / `$PSItem` inside a script block is meaningfully supported.

While `$_` is most typically used in the script blocks passed to the `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` cmdlets, there are other useful applications, most typically seen with the `Rename-Item` cmdlet: a [delay-bind script-block argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375):

```bash
# Example: rename *.txt files to *.dat files using a delay-bind script block:
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + '.dat' } -WhatIf
```

That is, instead of passing a *static* new name to `Rename-Item`, you pass a *script block that is evaluated for each input object* - with the input object bound to `$_`, as usual - which enables dynamic behavior.

As explained in the linked answer, however, this technique only works with parameters that are both (a) pipeline-binding and (b) *not* `[object]` or `[scriptblock]` typed; therefore, given that `Write-Object`'s `-Object` parameter *is* `[object]` typed, the technique does *not* work:

```bash
 # Try to enclose all inputs in [...] on output.
 # !! DOES NOT WORK.
 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | write-host -Object { "[$_]" }
```

Therefore, a pipeline-based solution requires the use of `ForEach-Object` in this case:

```bash
# -Object is optional
PS> 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | ForEach-Object { write-host -Object "[$_]" }
[foo]
[bar]
[baz]
```

---

##### Contexts in which `$_` (and its alias, `$PSItem`) is meaningfully defined:

What these contexts have in common is that **the `$_` / `$PSItem` reference must be made *inside a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)***, namely one **passed to / used in**:

- ... the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlets; e.g.:

  ```bash
  1..3 | ForEach-Object { 1 + $_ } # -> 2, 3, 4
  ```
- ... the intrinsic [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) and intrinsic [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) methods; e.g.:

  ```bash
  (1..3).ForEach({ 1 + $_ }) # -> 2, 3, 4
  ```
- ... a parameter, assuming that parameter allows a script block to act as a [delay-bind script-block parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters); e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Rename all *.txt files to *.dat files.
  Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + '.dat' } -WhatIf
  ```
- ... conditionals and associated script blocks inside a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # -> 'is one or three: one', 'is one or three: three'
  switch ('one', 'two', 'three') {
    { $_ -in 'one', 'three' } { 'is one or three: ' + $_ }
  }
  ```
- ... simple `function` and `filters`; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # -> 2, 3
  function Add-One { process { 1 + $_ } }; 1..2 | Add-One

  # -> 2, 3
  filter Add-One { 1 + $_ }; 1..2 | Add-One
  ```
- ... direct subscriptions to an object's event (n/a to the script block that is passed to the `-Action` parameter of a `Register-ObjectEvent` call); e.g::<sup>Tip of the hat to [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon).</sup>

  ```bash
  # In a direct event-subscription script block used in the
  # context of WinForms; e.g:
  $txtBox.Add_KeyPress({ 
    param($sender, $eventArgs)
    # The alternative to the explicitly defined parameters above is:
    # $this ... implicitly the same as $sender, i.e. the event-originating object
    # $_ / $PSItem ... implicitly the same as $eventArgs, i.e. the event-arguments object.
  })
  ```
- ... the [`[ValidateScript()]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) attribute in parameter declarations; note that for *array*-valued parameters the script block is called *for each element*; e.g.,

  ```bash
  function Get-Foo {
    param(
      [ValidateScript({ 0 -eq ($_ % 2) })]
      [int[]] $Number
    )
    "All numbers are even: $Number"
  }
  ```
- [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only: ... the substitution operand of the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # -> 'a10, 'a20'
  'a1', 'a2' -replace '\d+', { 10 * [int] $_.Value }
  ```
- ... in the context of `<ScriptBlock>` elements in [formatting files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) (but *not* in the context of script block-based [ETS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763)  members, where `$this` is used instead).
- ... in the context of using *PowerShell SDK methods* such as [`.InvokeWithContext()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext)

  ```bash
  # -> 43
  { 1 + $_ }.InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('_', 42), $null)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) has indicated in the comments. `$_` or `$PSItem` is the current object in the pipeline that is being processed. Typically, you see this with commands that require a processing or script block. You would have to contain your `Write-Host` command within a similar processing block.

```
'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | ForEach-Object {write-host $_}
```

Here is an example using the process block of a function:

```
function write-stuff {
    process { write-host $_ }
}

'foo', 'bar', 'baz' | write-stuff
bar
foo
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

$_ will *never* work outside a scriptblock. How about write-output instead:

```
'hi' | Write-Output -InputObject { $_ + ' there' } 

hi there
```