# How to recursively call a Java program with PowerShell and pass in a file path

Tags: java, powershell, batch-rename

I am trying to batch rename files in a folder. For example, right now I want to remove the character at the second index in the names of all of the files in a given folder. I have written a Java program that will do this given the path of the file.

The problem is that I am trying to batch the process with PowerShell, and I have very little knowledge of PowerShell. I basically just started using it today, and mainly to test run my Java program from the command line. I decided to try PowerShell for this because I saw a YouTube video where someone used PowerShell recursively to remove a certain character (like a "-") from every spot it appears in every file name in a folder. I thought maybe I could recurse with PowerShell to batch the process of changing every file name.

I want to recursively call the Java program with PowerShell and have PowerShell pass in each path of each file one by one in a folder to the Java program. I don't know if this is possible, but I'm hoping it is.

I have tried the following, though since I don't really any knowledge of PowerShell, I don't really know what to try. "Copy" is the name of the folder in which the files I want to modify are located.

```
get-childitem -recurse | java -cp "C:\Users\Media PC\Documents\Renamer\src\main\java" org.example.Main $_.name
```

I am getting the Java program to run, because I'm getting an error back from the program saying I didn't pass in a proper file path.

Comment: You would need to place your call inside a `Foreach-Object`  (`%` is the alias) loop to process them as they come down the pipeline: `.... | % { java .... $_.FullName }`. You would want to pass the `FullName` property as it's the entire path and while doing a *recursive* pull. This is because, the directory you're currently on is where it would attempt to resolve the path to.

Comment: Of course, you could do the recursion in the app. The nio classes and the visitor classes make this easy

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala)'s helpful comment:

Leaving aside the fact that invoking an external program (i.e., creation of a *child process*) *file by file* is inefficient:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  java -cp "C:\Users\Media PC\Documents\Renamer\src\main\java" org.example.Main $_.FullName
}
```

<sup>Note: The `-File` switch limits results to just *files* (doesn't include *directories*).</sup>

- PowerShell's [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) can only be used inside [*script blocks* (`{ ... }`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), so using `$_.name` as an argument *as-is* won't work.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55667981/45375) for all contexts in which `$_` is meaningfully defined.
- In order to pass an argument to a command that *isn't designed to take its input directly from the pipeline*, use the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet for custom-processing of each input object *one at a time*.

  - Inside the script block passed to it, you *can* use `$_` to refer to the pipeline input object at hand.
  - [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) outputs instances of the following .NET types:

    - [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo)(for *directories*) and
    - [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) (for *files*)
    - Their `.FullName` property contains their *full, file-system-native path*, so `$_.FullName` is a robust way to refer to just that. Given that `.Name` only reports the mere file *name*, it wouldn't be sufficient to identify the file at hand in a *recursive* traversal of the current dir.

      - In [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you could use just `$_`, because there such instances *consistently* stringify as the value of their `.FullName` property (when passing arguments to an *external program*, objects are *implicitly* stringified)  - unfortunately, this is *not* the case in *Windows PowerShell*; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400031/45375).