# How can I assign the value of $_ in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

`Set-Variable -Force` does not work. I want to assign the value of it. I don't care if you think that's incorrect or something.

I tried it and it didnt work.

Comment: Take it easy partner :-) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494115/what-does-mean-in-powershell

Comment: Basically, you can, but *not* in a persistent way, and it’s not generally a good idea - the value is automatically assigned by Powershell in a variety of  contexts so any changes you make get destroyed when the context goes out of scope - for example at the end of each ```foreach-object``` iteration (see @mklement0’s answer below). However, if you show some example code where you feel the need to assign a value to ```$_``` it might help explain the reason for your question, and might help you find an alternate approach…

Answer (score 3):

[`$_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) (aka `$PSItem`) is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables), i.e. one controlled by PowerShell itself, and therefore *shouldn't be assigned to*.

However, you can get *PowerShell* to set it for you, via an auxiliary [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call:

```bash
ForEach-Object -InputObject 'custom value for $_' {

  # Inside this block, $_ is now set to whatever you passed to -InputObject

  "`$_ is now: $_"  # -> '$_ is now: custom value for $_'

}
```

For more information about `$_` and the contexts in which it is meaningfully defined by PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55667981/45375).

Comment: Interestingly, it seems you *can* directly assign values to ```$_``` (inside a ```foreach-object``` at least - I haven’t tried other contexts) - for example ```@( "aaa", "bbb" ) | foreach-object { write-host $_; $_ = "xxx"; write-host $_ }``` outputs ```xxx``` from the second ```write-host``` call, but the changes are “lost”(by design) when the current context ends (e.g. at the end of every ```foreach-object``` iteration). I’d still say it’s not a good idea to do though, even if it works (to a limited extent) :-).

Comment: Indeed, @mclayton, you _technically can_, and that's why I said _you shouldn't_ (which you agree with), instead of _you cannot_. For a (lengthy) discussion from 6 years ago, see [GitHub issue #3695](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3695). Perhaps also of interest: the feature request in [GitHub issue #3830](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3830), which was declined.