# Can anyone please explain me what this ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null} command means in poweshell?

Tags: azure, powershell

## Get all the Network Interfaces

$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}

I am stuck on ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null} can anyone help?

Comment: As answered by @Abdul, the question mark (`?`) is a shortcut for the [`Where-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) and what follows between the curly brackets is a comparison expression as answered by @RithwikBojja-MT. The important issue here to mention is that the statement is not according to the best practice as `$Null` should be at the left hand side of the comparison operator (in this case `-NE`), see: [**Checking for `$Null`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null#checking-for-null)

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}

***NE*** is Comparision Operator which means ***Not Equals*** and ***$_*** means it is using the present item. So, it means finding those Virtual Machines which are not equal to null in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

`?` is an alias for `Where-Object` Cmdlet. That means

```
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | ?{ $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}
```

is equivalent to

```
$nics = Get-AzNetworkInterface | Where-Object { $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null}
```

Here [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) selects objects from a collection based on their property values and [`$_` is a variable to refer the current item in the collection.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3494138/6699447)