# Search string and replace another string in the row

Tags: search, replace

I have a csv-file with data like this:

```
"89216865";"89216865";"Alternator";"PowerMax";"4543"
"MG 149";"MG 149";"MAHLE Alternator";"MAHLE AM GmbH";"4543"
"MG 258";"MG 258";"MAHLE Alternator";"MAHLE AM GmbH";"4543"
"MS 222";"MS 222";"MAHLE Starter";"MAHLE AM GmbH";"4543"
"MS 241";"MS 241";"MAHLE Starter";"MAHLE AM GmbH";"4543"
"MS 29";"MS 29";"MAHLE Starter";"MAHLE AM GmbH";"4543"
"MS 386";"MS 386";"MAHLE Starter";"MAHLE AM GmbH";"4543"
"MS 645";"MS 645";"MAHLE Starter";"MAHLE AM GmbH";"4543"
"MS 230";"MS 230";"MAHLE Starter";"MAHLE AM GmbH";"4543"
"3300216";"3300216";"Alternator OE";"PowerMax";"4543"
"9213171";"9213171";"Alternator";"PowerMax";"4543"
"8212676";"8212676";"Starter";"PowerMax";"4543"
"9214266";"9214266";"Alternator";"PowerMax";"4543"
```

I need to replace the string "4543" with "287" in every row where "MAHLE AM GmbH" appears.

I have tried this.

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\SvcBI\Documents\Autodoc\Autodoc_Temp.csv" | 
Foreach-Object ($_ -match "MAHLE AM GmbH") {-replace "4543", "287"} | 
Set-Content C:\Users\SvcBI\Documents\Autodoc\POWERMAX_DK_2.csv
```

Please help /Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Powershell.

One way to do it could be reading the lines, and if the line contains the value, the perform the replacement.

See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494115/what-does-mean-in-powershell) for the meaning of `$_`

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\SvcBI\Documents\Autodoc\Autodoc_Temp.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Contains("MAHLE AM GmbH")) {
        $_.Replace("4543", "287") 
    } else { $_ }
} | Set-Content C:\Users\SvcBI\Documents\Autodoc\POWERMAX_DK_2.csv
```