# Usage of _ in scala lambda functions

Tags: scala

Can anyone please explain me why I can do:

```
a.mapValues(_.size)
```

instead of

```
a.mapValues(x => x.size)
```

but I can't do

```
a.groupBy(_)
```

instead of a

```
a.groupBy(x => x)
```

Comment: You can use `identity` in cases where you need function `x => x`: `a groupBy identity`

Comment: @incrop Thanks for the tip, I never noticed the identity function was already in `Predef`...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It isn't easy to see it here:

```
a.groupBy(_)
```

But it's easier to see it in something like this:

```
a.mkString("<", _, ">")
```

I'm partially applying the method/function. I'm applying it to some parameters (the first and last), and leaving the second parameter unapplied, so I'm getting a new function like this:

```
x => a.mkString("<", x, ">")
```

The first example is just a special case where the sole parameter is partially applied. When you use underscore on an expression, however, it stands for positional parameters in an anonymous function.

```
a.mapValues(_.size)
a.mapValues(x => x.size)
```

It is easy to get confused, because they both result in an anonymous function. In fact, there's a third underscore that is used to convert a method into a method value (which is also an anonymous function), such as:

```
a.groupBy _
```

Answer (score 50):

When you write `a.groupBy(_)` the compiler understands it as an anonymous function:

```
x => a.groupBy(x)
```

According to Scala Specifications §6.23, an underscore placeholder in an expression is replaced by a anonymous parameter. So:

- `_ + 1` is expanded to `x => x + 1`
- `f(_)` is expanded to `x => f(x)`
- `_` is not expanded by itself (the placeholder is not part of any expression).

The expression `x => a.groupBy(x)` will confuse the compiler because it cannot infer the type of `x`. If `a` is some collection of type `E` elements, then the compiler expects `x` to be a function of type `(E) => K`, but type `K` cannot be inferred...

Comment: Thank you. But, why then isn't the `a.mapValues(_.size)` interpreted as `x => a.mapValues(x.size)` ?

Comment: Because `_.size` is an expression. Compare: `List(1,2,3).map( 2 + twice(_) )` with `List(1,2,3).map( twice(1+_) )`, where `twice` is a function doubling the input.

Comment: @paradigmatic: But `_` is an expression too; its an expression that denotes a value on which a method is called. And the whole `a.mapValues(_.size)` is an expression too. As is whatever block contains this line. I think I've got an intuitive mostly-right handle on how it works, but is there a good definition of exactly "how far out" the Scala compiler will go? i.e. why it *doesn't* stop at just turning `_` into `x => x`, but *does* stop at turning `_.size` into `x => s.size`?

Comment: I think it stops after the first method application. Remember that `_.size`, `_ + 1`, `fn(_)` etc. are all translated to method applications in Scala.

Comment: @Ben: `_` makes a function out of the innermost `Expr` that properly contains it. The wording “properly contains” means “contains `_` *and also something else,* at least one other word or symbol”. That excludes `_` alone from being the identity function. An `Expr` is a particular kind of expression. It’s a grammatical distinction. In particular each argument of a function call, and pretty much any other expression in parentheses, is an `Expr`.