# Detect type of parameters in a function passed to flatMap on a list of Ints

Tags: scala, types

Why does this fail:

```
(1 to 10).flatMap(List(_+1))
```

with:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1))
```

I have to do:

```
(1 to 10).toList.flatMap( (x: Int) => List(x+1))
```

Why can't it detect the type automatically same as in:

```
(1 to 10).flatMap(List(_))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can detect the argument type automatically, as long as it's not buried too deep:

```
(1 to 10).flatMap(x => List(x + 1))
```

Maybe it's trying to treat the function literal `(_ + 1)` as the argument to `List.apply`?

Comment: *Maybe it's trying to treat the function literal (_ + 1) as the argument to List.apply?* Yes, that's correct. You can only use the `_` syntax for really simple expressions.

Comment: This answer might help explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673545/usage-of-in-scala-lambda-functions/7673633#7673633

Comment: ah yeah, that makes sense to me now. It is trying to pass (_+1) to apply, as you said