# Scala Type Inference : Group By

Tags: scala, types

I've a question about type inferencing in scala. The following code snippet fails in REPL

```
scala> "abbccc".groupBy(_)
```

with this error:

```
<console>:9: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => "abbccc".groupBy(x$1))
              "abbccc".groupBy(_)
```

However it succeeds if I do this :

```
scala> "abbccc".groupBy(_.toChar)
```

As per my understanding , _.toChar is just syntactic sugar for {x => x.toChar}. So in the first case where I wrote `"abbccc".groupBy(_)`, this should just mean `"abbccc".groupBy({x=>x})` . Why isn't scala able to infer that this mapping is from a char to char without an explicit "toChar"?

Comment: Another dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673545/usage-of-in-scala-lambda-functions

Comment: The first link doesn't really answer my question, it gives an alternative solution to solve the problem. But the second one does. Thanks!!

Comment: Also I tried searching this question before posting it but I couldn't find it. Can you tell me how did you go about searching for this question?

Comment: I searched for `scala underscore identity` but I knew what I had to search for...