# How to join two ArrayList(List(String)] in parallel join

Tags: scala, concatenation

I have two ArrayList(List[String]) e.g:

```
ArrayList1:           ArrayList1:
List(a, b, c)         List(1, 2, 3)
List(d, e, f)         List(4, 5, 6)
List(g,h, i)          List(7,8, 9)
```

I want to use scala to join in parallel such as doing this

```
val ArrayList12 = ArrayList1 ++ ArrayList2
```

but this is not what I want since the ArrayList2 got added at the end of ArrayList1

Please I will appreciate help using scala to  have a parallel join in this form:

```
List(a, b, c,1,2,3) 
List(d, e, f,4,5,6)
List(g,h,i,7,8,9)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip.

```
val arrayList12 = arrayList1.zip(arrayList2).map(tuple => tuple._1 ++ tuple._2)
```

`zip` returns a List that combines each element of the first and the second list into a `Tuple2`, the resulting type is `Seq[(List[A],List[Int])]`.
Then we can map that list to to a flat structure with `map` to concatenate the two lists in the Tuple.

Comment: Surely .map(x => x._1 ++ x._2) ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Same thing, Scala allows this shorter syntax aswell :) See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673545/usage-of-in-scala-lambda-functions

Comment: But isn't the _ *positional* - that is, using it twice suggests two different args, whereas in fact you want the one argument (the tuple) with the two fields ?

Comment: Did you try the `flatten` one? Hint: it doesn't work, there's no `flatten` for tuples. And the first doesn't compile either (extra `.` before the digit)

Comment: @BrianAgnew, I got it with 
val arrayList12 = arrayList1.zip(arrayList2).map(x => x._1 ++ x._2) .Thanks

Comment: @TaiwoO.Adetiloye - Good to know. I've just undeleted my answer following your comment

Comment: Sorry about that, reversed the extra dots.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Got rid of `flatten`.

Comment: My REPL (Scala 2.10) doesn't like 'List((1,2),(3,4)).map(_._1 + _._2)'. Does yours ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew,  not even for Scala 2.11 that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scala>  List(List("a","b","c"), List("d", "e", "f"))
res1: List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b, c), List(d, e, f))

scala>  List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6))
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))

scala> res1.zip(res2)
res3: List[(List[String], List[Int])] = List((List(a, b, c),List(1, 2, 3)), (List(d, e, f),List(4, 5, 6)))
```

which gives a `List` of tuples. You can then `map()` across these, adding the two elements of each tuple:

```
scala> res1.zip(res2).map(x => x._1 ++ x._2)
res5: List[List[Any]] = List(List(a, b, c, 1, 2, 3), List(d, e, f, 4, 5, 6))
```

Comment: I don't think I did. I tried yours in the REPL with no joy, due to the positional placeholders

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul - just done that following comments

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Honest mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of skinning the cat:

```
val arrayList1 = List(List("a","b","c"), List("d", "e", "f"), List("g","h", "i"))
val arrayList2 =List(List("1","2","3"), List("4", "5", "6"), List("7", "8", "9"))
List(arrayList1, arrayList2).transpose.map(_.flatten)
// List(List(a, b, c, 1, 2, 3), List(d, e, f, 4, 5, 6), List(g, h, i, 7, 8, 9))
```

But if I were doing it for real, I'd use Brian Agnew's answer