# scala and groupby: value Unzip is not a member

Tags: scala

```
val numbers = List(1,4,5,1,6,5,6)
numbers.groupBy(x=>x)    // Run OK
numbers.groupBy(_)       // ERROR
```

only by curiosity: somebody know why the second doesn't run ¿?

ERROR:Error:(8, 4) value Unzip is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Char, Int)]
C.Unzip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of \_ in scala lambda functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673545/usage-of-in-scala-lambda-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler interprets `numbers.groupBy(_)` as `x => numbers.groupBy(x)`, which is clearly not what you intended. If you dislike the redundant `x => x`, you can use the predefined identity function:

```
numbers.groupBy(identity)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,groupby fucntoins take functions and return group by values .

definition of groupby :-
def groupBy[K](f: A => K): immutable.Map[K, Repr]

In your coding 
numbers.groupBy(x=>x)    // Run OK because x treats as function literal/values
numbers.groupBy(_)       // ERROR because _ is place holder for parameter ,not an function values/literal