# MVC 3 Render Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've had some problems when I try to render a PartialView.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new fanganielloEntities();
        List<imovel> imoveis = (from s in db.imovel
                                where s.StatusImovel == 3
                                select s).ToList();

        return PartialView(imoveis);
    }

     public ActionResult Listar()
     {
         return View();
     }
```

The View:

```
 @Html.Partial("TesteLista")
```

The Partial:

```
@model List Mvc4Web.Models.imovel
    @if (Model != null)
    {
foreach (var item in Model)
{
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescricaoImovel)
 }
    }
```

The Error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 5:   Line 6:   Line 7:  @foreach (var item in Model)  Line 8:   {
>   Line 9:

Thank in advanced!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should pass Model to the partial View

In your View

```
 @model List<Mvc4Web.Models.imovel>
@Html.Partial("TesteLista",Model)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still getting the same result: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: For the line `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescricaoImovel)` I believe you'll need `@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.DescricaoImovel)` as this doesn't appear to be a valid lambda expression - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097995/i-want-to-understand-the-lambda-expression-in-html-displayformodelitem-mymo and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Html.Partial` will not fire your controller action.  If you want to fire the Index action when TesteLista is rendered, use

```
@Html.Action("TesteLista")
```

instead.

Comment: Thats what I got: A public action method 'TesteLista' was not found on controller 'Mvc4Web.Controllers.TesteController'.

Comment: @Rodney 'TesteLista' is not action it partial view so you only have Partial View. and insead of checkinh if(Model !=null) check if(Model.Count >0) and check whether you are passing Model in View or not and same model forwarding to partial view.

Comment: @Rodney, rename Index() to TesteLista().