# Using a dictionary lookup with Html.DisplayFor in an ASP.NET View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I'm learning to write MVC websites in C# with ASP.NET and the Entity Framework.

However, I'm struggling to write a dictionary lookup that would work with the `Html.DisplayFor` method.

Say I have the following two models:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int BreedId;
    (...)
}

public class Breed
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    (...)
}
```

Then, somewhere in the controller, I'm creating a dictionary containing all the *Breeds*, indexed by the `Id`, and assigning it to `ViewBag.Breeds`.

In the `Dogs/Index` View, I use something like that:

```
@model IEnumerable<App.Models.Dog>

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @(ViewBag.Breeds[item.BreedId].Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And it generates a table of the *Dogs* and their *Breeds*, as intended.

However, if I try to use the dictionary lookup inside the `Html.DisplayFor` method, I get an error because *an expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation*:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ViewBag.Breeds[item.BreedId].Name)
```

Casting it to an explicitly typed dictionary doesn't work either:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ((Dictionary<int, Breed>)ViewBag.Breeds)[item.BreedId].Name)
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097995/i-want-to-understand-the-lambda-expression-in-html-displayformodelitem-item) which explores why `DisplayFor` has such a funny syntax.  It isn't just a simple function that accepts a string.  It accepts an expression, which is never executed but parsed, so that the Razor engine can find one of the model's properties and all of its attributes-- that is how is discovers scaffolding and knows how to render a model member.

Bottom line is-- you can't just put any old string in `DisplayFor`.  But then again, you shouldn't need to-- to display a string, you don't need it.

**Option 1**

Instead of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ViewBag.Breeds[item.BreedId].Name)
```

Just use

```
@ViewBag.Breeds[item.BreedId].Name
```

or if your breed names might contain a `<` or `&` character, you might need to HTML-escape them, so use

```
@Html.Encode(ViewBag.Breeds[item.BreedId].Name)
```

**Option 2**

If you really want to take advantage of `DisplayFor` and MVC scaffolding, add the desired computed field to the model itself, and reference it plainly in the view.

```
public class Dog
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int BreedId;

    [Display(Name = "Breed Name")]  //Optional scaffolding attributes
    public string BreedName
    {
        get 
        {
            return ViewBag.Breeds[BreedId].Name;
        }
    }
}
```

and in your view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BreedName)
```