# can html dropdownlistfor take no input parameters in lambda expression?

Tags: asp.net, lambda

so I'm trying to understand how this works a bit better, but when I use

```
html.dropdownlistfor(model => item.Location ....
```

this is considered ok, but if I try to do

```
html.dropdownlistfor( () => item.Location ....
```

The function doesn't take it. Is there a particular reason this doesn't work?

Comment: In the first one, model is your screen model, so you are assigning values to model's property using item and lambda. The second one, () is an anonymous lambda, and it never assigns value to any of your model items.

Comment: so model is an actual named variable referring to the screen model? I don't think I've read this anywhere. Was it in the docs? So if I use some other named word, will it fail too?

I thought that the lambda was passing in model but not using it since item.location is called instead. I thought that item was an enclosed variable from the closure as opposed to an actual input

Comment: Look at the Details.cshtml in this sample app : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller It is declared `@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie` and used as `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)`. There is no explicit declaration for models.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to understand is whether the "model" in the code you just wrote is a keyword or not. They seem to use

ModelItem, model, etc interchangeably, so I'm guessing what you name the parameter is not important, it just gets passed the model based on the annotation at the top ("@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie").

However, I'm guessing that item is a keyword because a List<Models> is being passed to the view in the controller, correct?

Comment: Correct. Whatever you have declared with model during view initialization, you should use the same variable to bind the data not anonymous functions/lambda.

Comment: I guess what's confusing me is why in the documentation are there lines like this:

 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)

on the page you linked, I don't see anything defining a modelItem property, so I assumed that it didn't matter what I used for the name of the input property in the expression lambda

Comment: See this SO post and answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10098268/311255