# Why do the ASP.NET MVC template views use Html.DisplayFor to display data that is not part of the model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC 4. Some of the default template views contain something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeModel>
...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Property1)
</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Property2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My understanding is that the `DisplayFor` takes an expression where the input parameter is the view's Model and the return value is any object, and finds the appropriate DisplayTemplate for the returned object.

Based on this, I can see why `DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Property1)` *works*, but it doesn't feel like the right choice. If I'm not using the `modelItem` parameter at all, why use `DisplayFor`? Is there no method like `GetDisplayTemplate(item.Property1)`?

Comment: I think the unique situation you are finding is that your model is `IEnumerable<T>`. This isn't always the case.. and then, it makes sense to say `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Property1);`. For example, if you had a partial view that rendered each item.. the above would be true.

Comment: @Simon: Why is `DisplayFor` tied to the Model's type? I.e., why can't I write something like `@Html.DisplayFor<SomeType>(item => item.Property1)`?

Comment: That would be a question for the MVC framework designers :P

Comment: See this So Q&A, I think the answer explains it in the last 2 paras, why is it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097995/i-want-to-understand-the-lambda-expression-in-html-displayformodelitem-item

Answer (score 1):

Technically as you say the modelItem is totally unused. This is an example of a parameterless lambda. I tend to use _=> in this situation. I do this as that is what we have got used to although I suppose it does look a bit odd. It makes it far easier to generate editorfor etc when looping over lists. There is no other strongly typed way of calling DisplayFor/EditorFor that I know

See this question for explanation [Is there a better way to express a parameterless lambda than () =>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424775/is-there-a-better-way-to-express-a-parameterless-lambda-than)