# How to extract words from structured string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
"select model (field1, field2, field3, ...)"
```

And I would like to write something that extracts the words where *model* and the *fields* are.

So for instance:

```
select Car (door, wheel, antenna)
```

Method 1 returns `Car`.
Method 2 returns List/Array `{door, wheel, antenna}`

So in other words, I am looking for `extractModel()` and `extractFields()`.

I feel like `RegEx` is needed here, but I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Do you mean that "select model (field1, field2, ...)" is your source string and you're trying to capture values in the string?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: Is the input string _always_ in the _exact_ format "`select $object ($field[, $field[, ...]])`"? If so, have you tried building a regex that captures that?

Comment: Yes it is always in that structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var m = "select Car (door, wheel, antenna)";
Regex r = new Regex(@"select\s+(.*)\s+\((.*)\)");
var model = r.Match(m).Groups[1].Value;
// untrimmmed:
// var fields = r.Match(m).Groups[2].Value.Split(',');
// trimmed:
var fields = r.Match(m).Groups[2].Value.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd add a `.Select(Trim).ToArray()` to trim the input.

Comment: A few points on that `.Select(_ => _.Trim());`: [`_` is the syntax for an ignored parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424775/is-there-a-better-way-to-express-a-parameterless-lambda-than) (`s` would suffice), you can abbreviate it to `Select(Trim)` and you'd want this result materialized (`.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`) as you'll probably iterate it somewhere anyhow, and this would make multiple enumerations or other operations safe and possible. So please make it `.Select(Trim).ToList()` (or `ToArray()`) and you have my upvote back. ;-)

Comment: I use '_' routinely - a habbit. Agree with `ToArray()` - added. But the `Select(Trim)` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Another direction to go:

```
select (\S*) \(([^)]*)
```

The second match group is a comma separated list, and you split on it.

http://rubular.com/r/ByLODRGVdy