# Difference between lambda expressions and anonymous methods - C#

Tags: c#, .net

**Duplicate:** [delegate keyword vs. lambda notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299703/c-delegate-keyword-vs-lambda-notation)

I understand the anonymous methods can be used to define delegates and write inline functions. Is using Lambda expressions any different from this?

I guess I am a little confused on when to use what.

**Edit:
Also, appears that to use either anonymous or lambdas, there needs to be an Extension method for the type?**

Answer (score 16):

A lambda expression is simply shortcut syntax for an anonymous method.  Anonymous methods look like this:

```
delegate(params) {method body}
```

The equivalent lambda expression would look like this:

```
params => method body
```

In short, all lambda expressions are anonymous methods, but it is possible to have an anonymous method that is not written in lambda syntax (like the first example above).  Hope this is helpful!

Comment: +1, but aren't lambda expressions just reinventing the wheel (rather poorly, as I though anonymous methods made more sense).

Comment: so lambada expression can NOT have return valuess? while anonymous method can?

Comment: SnOrfus: yes they do the same thing so you're right, it's just a matter of syntax preference.  Sasha: both lambdas and anonymous methods can have return values.

Comment: Lambdas make the use of anonymous delegates much more terse through syntax shortcuts and type inference.

i = l.Count(delegate(string x) { return x.Length == 2; });
i = l.Count(x => x.Length == 2);

Comment: lambdas use implied typing, so "(x, y) => x + y;" is much more concise than "delegate(int x, int y) { return x + y; }"  Use lambdas when they promote readability, and anonymous delegates when they make sense.

Answer (score 6):

Lambda expressions can be converted to expression trees, while anonymous delegates cannot.

Answer (score 6):

Only lambda expression without method body can be converted to expression tree

Following constructs **do** compile:

```
            Func<int> exp1 = () => 1;
            Func<int> exp2 = () => { return 1; };
            Func<int> exp3 = delegate { return 1; };
            Expression<Func<int>> exp4 = () => 1;
```

And following do **not**

```
Expression<Func<int>> exp5 = delegate { return 1; }; //no anonymous delegates
Expression<Func<int>> exp6 = () => { return 1; }; //or lambdas with block body
```

So there is difference even on not very advanced level ( that Jon Skeet points out here [sick difference example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299703/c-delegate-keyword-vs-lambda-notation/299858#299858) )

Another difference is that you can create anonymous delegates without parameter list if you don't plan to use them inside method body, with lambda you always have to provide parameters.

Following two lines demonstrate the difference

```
Func<int, int, int, int, int> anonymous = delegate { return 1; };
Func<int, int, int, int, int> lambda = (param1, param2, param3, param4) => 1;
```

You do essentially the same thing but anonymous delegate clearly looks better here.

Answer (score 4):

Not really no.  They are essentially the exact same feature with different syntax constructs.   The general shift appears to be away from the C# 2.0 anonymous method syntax towards the lambda style syntax for both anonymous expressions and functions though.