# Is it possible to declare a method as a parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, input, parameters

For example the main method I want to call is this:

```
public static void MasterMethod(string Input){
    /*Do some big operation*/
}
```

Usually, I would do something like this this:

```
public static void StringSelection(int a)
{
    if(a == 1)
    {
       return "if";
    }
    else
    {
       return "else";
    }
}

MasterMethod(StringSelection(2));
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
MasterMethod( a = 2
     {
        if(a == 1)
        {
           return "if";
        }
        else
        {
           return "else";
        }
     });
```

Where 2 is somehow passed into the operation as an input.

Is this possible?  Does this have a name?

EDIT::  Please note, the MasterMethod is an API call.  I cannot change the parameters for it.  I accidentally made a typo on this.

Comment: Note: You have a void method returning a string - which won't compile.  My answer switches that around.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this via [delegates in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx):

```
public static string MasterMethod(int param, Func<int,string> function)
{
    return function(param);
}


// Call via:
string result = MasterMethod(2, a => 
{
    if(a == 1)
    {
       return "if";
    }
    else
    {
       return "else";
    }
 });
```

Comment: Of course, this only makes sense if the 2 is in a variable, not a literal. :-)

Comment: Yeah, of course - just matching the code to the question [Was: MasterMethod(StringSelection(2));]

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with anon delegates:

```
    delegate string CreateString();

    public static void MasterMethod(CreateString fn)
    {
        string something = fn();
        /*Do some big operation*/
    }

    public static void StringSelection(int a)
    {
        if(a == 1)
        {
           return "if";
        }
        else
        {
           return "else";
        }
    }

    MasterMethod(delegate() { return StringSelection(2); });
```

Answer (score 2):

[anonymous methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761236/difference-between-lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-methods-c)

Comment: @Steven i'd edit but think the answer's fairly well covered elsewhere already.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28VS.71%29.aspx). Which include [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80).aspx).