# How can I combine multiple statement in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new to this LINQ field and one thing am trying to do.

I have an action delegate(written below) which i want to convert in lambda expression.

```
      Action<string> custom = delegate(string name)
            {
                lstCutomers.Add(new Customer(name, coutries[cnt]));
                name = name + " Object Created";
            };
```

What will be the lambda expression for same. I just want to know that can i write multiple statements in lambda if no then Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can write a single statement or a block of statement

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299703/delegate-keyword-vs-lambda-notation for a detailled discussion about the delegate notation Vs Lambda notation.

Comment: You realize that assigning a value back to `name` isn't going to have any effect, right? So your second statement is irrelevant, and you can use a non-statement lambda. Either you've given a bad example, or you've probably got a bug in your code...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't create a lambda *expression*, since you're not returning anything. You can however create a *statement* lambda:

```
Action<string> custom = (name) =>
        {
            lstCutomers.Add(new Customer(name, coutries[cnt]));
            name = name + " Object Created";
        };
```

Comment: that would be the anonymous method. 

It should be something like  
Action<string> customLambda = 
(name) => lstCutomers.Add(new Customer(name, coutries[cnt]);name = name + " Object Created"; ); 

Which is not compiling even.

Comment: Not sure then, as `Expression`'s always end up with a value. I thought the `=>` made it a lambda expression (which is converted to an anonymous method because of the type of custom).

Comment: @DJ: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) `A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements` also, see the section on Statement Lambdas. Have updated my answer.

Comment: so it can contain multiple statements as well but i cant see any example of it.. do u have any where one lamda expressions has multiple statements?

Comment: See the first example in the Variable Scope in Lambda Expressions
heading on the MSDN page I linked to. The syntax is the same as a statement lambda, except you return something.

Comment: @DJ: It's fairly common in things like [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Except those are *statement* lambdas, since they wouldn't return anything.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: I was answering the OP's question about where one might use a lambda expression with multiple statements. Also, not returning anything is orthogonal to being a statement lambda: you can have statement lambdas which return values, and non-statement lambdas which don't.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Note that in your first comment, you're talking about `Expression`, which is only used when converting a lambda expression into an expression tree. That's irrelevant here. Both statement lambdas and non-statement lambdas are lambda expressions. (The spec doesn't actually use the term "statement lambda" - it talks about the lambda expressions with a body which is either an expression or a statement body.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ahh ok, didn't realise you could get statement lambdas that return things and visa-versa. Thanks for the corrections. :)