# Lambda expression to delegate instance or expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

*After reading this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299858/859154) -still I have a question*

A lambda expression is an unnamed method written in place of a delegate instance.
The compiler immediately converts the lambda expression to either:

- A delegate instance.
- An expression tree, of type Expression, representing the code inside
  the lambda expression in a traversable object model.

But *When* will it convert it do a *delegate instance* -- and *when* when it will convert it to expression tree ? ( didn't find related info on that one)

Not much of a related code - just tried to played with it  - obviously both a matching. I didn't think so because I thought one would be a better match .

```
void Main()
{
     Foo( () => 0 );
}
  void Foo(Func<int > action)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}

  void Foo(Expression<Func<int>> func)
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

This will result in error (ambiguous between the following methods or properties)

Comment: Not sure I understand. The same will go if you used your own delegate, say `delegate int Blah()` and have `void Foo(Blah blah)`.

Comment: @leppie the code is from what Jon wrote in the link , and I tried to play with it a bit. im just asking what makes a compiler translate it to delegate instance VS expression tree

Comment: It will convert to whichever form you've effectively asked it to. Your code is ambiguous because it could convert to either `Func<int>` or `Expression<Func<int>>` and neither conversions is deemed "better". It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @JonSkeet Are you saying that the context is what makes the compiler decide ? for example linq-2-sql will convert it to expression tree...?

Comment: Personally, I would not even bother with this kind of overload. Just give it a different name, problem solved ;p

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, Jon is saying it will be ambiguous in any context. LINQ uses a differentiator (`IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`) to do the disambiguation.

Comment: @leppie I know. I asked about the decision whether to convert it to expression tree VS delegate instance. forget my code

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, it's got nothing to do with LINQ to SQL - it's whether you're trying to convert the lambda expression to an `Expression<...>` or a delegate type. In your case, you've got valid conversions to both due to the overload.#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It converts to whichever type you've asked it to. For example:

```
Func<int> del = () => 0; // Conversion to delegate
Expression<Func<int>> expression = () => 0; // Conversion to expression tree
```

In your case, you're asking the compiler to *consider* conversions to both forms, because of overloading. If you removed the `Foo(Expression<Func<int>> func)` method, the code would be valid and the compiler would convert the lambda expression to a delegate. If you removed the other method instead, the code would be valid and the compiler would convert the lambda expression to an expression tree.