# How Are Anonymous Delegates Working in ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters

Tags: c#, asp.net, anonymous-delegates

I'm trying to make the move from PHP to ASP.NET and in doing so I'm trying to learn how the MVC works, however I'm stuck with the ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters as I don't understand what is happening.

The snippet I'm struggling with is the following:

```
protected virtual ActionExecutedContext InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList<IActionFilter> filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    ActionExecutingContext preContext = new ActionExecutingContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, parameters);
    Func<ActionExecutedContext> continuation = () =>
                                               new ActionExecutedContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, false /* canceled */, null /* exception */)
                                               {
                                                   Result = InvokeActionMethod(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, parameters)
                                               };

    // need to reverse the filter list because the continuations are built up backward
    Func<ActionExecutedContext> thunk = filters.Reverse().Aggregate(continuation,
                                                                    (next, filter) => () => InvokeActionMethodFilter(filter, preContext, next));
    return thunk();
}
```

The full source code can be found at the following URL:
https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerActionInvoker.cs#L371

In particular, I'm unsure on what the following is doing:

```
    Func<ActionExecutedContext> continuation = () =>
                                               new ActionExecutedContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, false /* canceled */, null /* exception */)
                                               {
                                                   Result = InvokeActionMethod(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, parameters)
                                               };
```

As I've never seen a line containing the following before:
continuation = () =>

Nor can I seem to find an answer on Google because it doesn't recognise = () => as a search term.

I'm just as confused with the following snippet of code which has a similar syntax:

```
    // need to reverse the filter list because the continuations are built up backward
    Func<ActionExecutedContext> thunk = filters.Reverse().Aggregate(continuation,
                                                                    (next, filter) => () => InvokeActionMethodFilter(filter, preContext, next));
```

Coming from a PHP background, I've not seen this syntax before, and the resources I've read online don't really clear things up for me either.

On the basis of the following SO question:
[delegate keyword vs. lambda notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299703/delegate-keyword-vs-lambda-notation)

If I was to rewrite the following...

```
    Func<ActionExecutedContext> continuation = () =>
                                               new ActionExecutedContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, false /* canceled */, null /* exception */)
                                               {
                                                   Result = InvokeActionMethod(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, parameters)
                                               };
```

Would it look like so...

```
    Func<ActionExecutedContext> continuation = delegate(new ActionExecutedContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, false /* canceled */, null /* exception */))
                                               {
                                                   Result = InvokeActionMethod(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, parameters)
                                               };
```

And same for the second snippet...

```
    // need to reverse the filter list because the continuations are built up backward
    Func<ActionExecutedContext> thunk = filters.Reverse().Aggregate(continuation,
                                                                    (next, filter) => () => InvokeActionMethodFilter(filter, preContext, next));
```

Which if I'm not mistaken would be...

```
    // need to reverse the filter list because the continuations are built up backward
    Func<ActionExecutedContext> thunk = filters.Reverse().Aggregate(continuation, delegate(next, filter) {InvokeActionMethodFilter(filter, preContext, next)});
```

Or am I still not getting it?

Comment: If you are asking what does  the `= () =>` syntax mean, it is assigning an anonymous delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), and in this particular case it is nothing more then anonymous functions.

> Which if I'm not mistaken would be...

Wrong. It is delegate to function with two parameters `next` and `filter`, that returns delegate to another function, that calls `InvokeActionMethodFilter` method:

```
Func<ActionExecutedContext> thunk =
    filters.Reverse()
           .Aggregate(continuation,
                      delegate(Func<ActionExecutedContext> next, IActionFilter filter)
                      {
                          return delegate
                          {
                              return InvokeActionMethodFilter(filter, preContext, next);
                          };
                      });
```

This code chains IActionFilters invocation until some of them produce result. And at the end of chain is your action method. Variable `next` is either filter executing function `() => InvokeActionMethodFilter(filter, preContext, next)`, or `continuation` at the end of chain. See `InvokeActionMethodFilter` implementation for details.

Comment: Thanks for your help with what you have said I should be able to explore this further. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, to help others coming from a PHP background, as I was slightly mistaken by what was happening, the following is a good resource on creating objects using an Object Initializer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx