# Assigning a delegate to a func that takes N parameters without explicitly declaring parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, func

Given a func that takes N parameters, why is it possible to assign a delegate to it that doesn't explicitly declare any parameters? e.g.

```
Func<int, string, object, string, bool> test;
// (1) this makes sense to me
test= delegate (int a, string b, object c, string d) { return true; };

// (2) this also makes sense to me
test= (a,b,c,d)=>true; 

// (3) why does this work? 
test = delegate { return true; };
```

Why does (3) work? Is there any difference between (1), (2), and (3)? Can we access the parameters from inside the braces of the third variation?

Comment: Anonymous methods are flexible, useful to write an event handler inline that just doesn't need the passed arguments.  Doesn't get used much anymore, most programmer opt for a lambda expression today.  The C# compiler can easily generate the correct code, it knows what concrete method it needs to generate from the delegate signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does (3) work?

From the [C# programming guide on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods):

> Anonymous methods enable you to omit the parameter list. This means that an anonymous method can be converted to delegates with a variety of signatures

---

> Is there any difference between (1), (2), and (3)?

[delegate keyword vs. lambda notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299703/delegate-keyword-vs-lambda-notation)

> Can we access the parameters from inside the braces of the third variation?

No. Don't omit the parameter list if you intend to use the parameters in your anonymous method.