# C# Variable = new function () {};

Tags: c#, function, variables

Within C# is it possible to create a new function on the fly to define a variable?

I know that

```
string getResult() {
    if (a)
        return "a";
    return "b";
}
String result = getResult();
```

is possible, but I'm looking for something like

```
String result = new string getResult() {
    if (a)
        return "a";
    return "b";
}
```

Is this possible? If so, would someone demonstrate?

***EDIT***
It is possible

**Edit: Final - Solution**

This is the end result of what I barbarically hacked together

```
Func<string> getResult = () =>
{
    switch (SC.Status)
    {
        case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
            return "Running";
        case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
            return "Stopped";
        case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
            return "Paused";
        case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
            return "Stopping";
        case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
            return "Starting";
        default:
            return "Status Changing";
    }
};

TrayIcon.Text = "Service Status - " + getResult();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to define such a function:

```
Func<bool, string> getResult = ( a ) => {
    if (a)
        return "a";
    return "b";
}
```

You can then invoke: `string foo = getResult( true );`. As a delegate, it can be stored/passed and invoked when needed.

Example:

```
string Foo( Func<bool, string> resultGetter ){
    return resultGetter( false );
}
```

You can also [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428617/what-are-closures-in-net) around variables within scope:

```
bool a = true;

Func<string> getResult = () => {
    if (a)
        return "a";
    return "b";
}

string result = getResult();
```

Comment: (If I understand the asker's intent...) I'd recommend against this, since it's not what `Func`s are typically used for, and would be confusing to future readers of your code (yourself included) that are more familiar with normal `Func` usage patterns.  Unless it's really an instance where a `Func` or `Action` would make more sense, either inline the code, or make it a separate method.

Comment: I would have to disagree. While I don't know what the OP's needs are and this is a contrived example, the ability to define and repeatedly/conditionally/eventually execute a delegate is both powerful and common. But that's just me.

Comment: This wouldn't really work for me as Tim S. stated. I'd rather just define it in a separate method, if I were to use this route. My only real purpose in doing this was to define it lazy style all in one line like Actionscript, or what I believe is also possible in Javo. Upon realizing it might be harder than I initially intend I was curious how it could be implemented, if it actually could be implemented.

Comment: You can define a delegate in one line but it's probably not the right fit if that's the only motivation for it.

Comment: The initial method mentioned would have worked, had I wanted to pass the ServiceController (the object my switch is built around in context) with each call to getResult. "getResult(ServiceController);" would have worked, but I didn't want that and looking at that part of your answer threw me off. I see now where you said you can close around variables within scope. This is actually exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for not noticing sooner.

Comment: This is lambda, not delegate though.

Comment: @liang - `Func<>` is a delegate, and the example shows a variable of a delegate type having a lambda assigned to it. I like this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/74414/453277

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the inline if statement.

```
string result = a ? "a" : "b";
```

Comment: I feel like this would work, except I'm actually trying to implement a switch. I simplified it to an if statement in my code for the sake of trying to be understood. Is there perhaps an inline switch statement?

Comment: you could do it with a `Dictionary`.

Comment: A `Dictionary` incurs a lot more overhead than a simple switch statement (relatively speaking). You generally should try to avoid using Dictionaries for logic known at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want inline you can make an extension method for type `String`:

```
static class StringExtensions {
    public static string ExecuteFunc(
            this string str, 
            Func<string, string> func
        ) {
        return func(str);
    }
}
```

And then, when you want to use it, you do so like so:

```
string str = "foo";

string result = str.ExecuteFunc( s => {
        switch(s){
            case "a":
                return "A";
            default:
                return "B";
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: +1 for using extension. Although it doesn't really pass function around. It can't be assigned once, but have to be assigned whenever invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the scope of the variable `a` is in your example, but assuming that it is accessible within the scope (as it is in your example):

```
Func<string> getResult = () =>
{
    return a ? "a" : "b";
}
```

Comment: `Action<T>`s don't return anything; did you mean `Func<string>`? Anyway, I think `var` would probably work...

Comment: @minitech, `var` doesn't work with lambdas.  There's not enough context for the compiler to know what to make of it. (the compiler error is "Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable")

Comment: @TimS.: You'd think it could intelligently determine the return type. Oh well.

Comment: @minitech or you can get ReSharper to extract the function as a variable and intelligently determine the return type :)

Comment: @minitech the root reason (or so I infer) is that `Func` and `Action` don't have any special status in the C# compiler - they're just delegates.  If you had a delegate defined that had the same signature, how could it know which you'd like it to be? E.g. even among very common built-in delegates, `Action<object, EventArgs>` and `EventHandler` are the same.

Comment: Using this I was able to create what I was looking for (A variable defined by a new function upon instantiation, all in the nice laziness of a "single line style"). It may not be as pretty as ActionScript, but it serves it's purpose. Thank you.

Comment: @BustyLoli-Chan if an answer is useful to you please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution you posted, here is a better way to do this.

Change your ServiceControllerStatus enum to add [Description] attributes:

```
public enum ServiceControllerStatus
{
    [Description("Running")]
    Running,
    // ... others
}
```

Add the following extension method in a new static class:

```
public static string ToDescription(this Enum value)
{
    var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
}
```

Now you can simply write:

```
TrayIcon.Text = "Service Status - " SC.Status.ToDescription();
```